# I have finished my plate

Tags: phrase-request

He didn't want to eat his dinner.

I was angry with him and went to take a shower.

When I took a shower, my son went to me and said.

> "I have finished my plate."
>
> "I have finished my dinner."

Do they sound natural to a native speaker?

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but '_I have finished my plate_' is not a sentence that I have heard being used that widely or commonly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I understand both phrases, neither sounds *natural* to me. "I have finished my dinner" is indeed [about ten times more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=finished%20my%20plate%2C%20finished%20my%20dinner&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfinished%20my%20plate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfinished%20my%20dinner%3B%2Cc0), but [even more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20finished%20my%20dinner%2C%20I%20have%20finished%20my%20dinner&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20finished%20my%20dinner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20have%20finished%20my%20dinner%3B%2Cc0) would be:

> I finished my dinner.

The simple past is what I would expect to hear and what I consider to be most natural for this context.

As an aside, a related phrase that you might utter in a restaurant would be:

> I am finished with my plate.

This would be something said to your waiter when finished with a course, whether or not everything in the plate had been eaten. But that's a little formal. A simple:

> I'm done with my plate.

would suffice there.

Answer (score 1):

(I am a native speaker)

**I have finished my dinner** is definitely used most of the time. **I have finished my plate**, however, is not very common. People will say "I have finished my plate **of pizza**", and in writing (not many people will speak like this), you may see something like "Johnny **cleared** his plate", and that will mean he finished everything on it.